# having issue with the HP Communication port(COM3)

Tags: python, windows, bluetooth, serial-communication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iV2L.png)

I am trying to send information from my python script through bluetooth to another system. In the code I am need to give the COM port for connecting. But, even though both the laptops are connected I am unable to send information from the script.

I am getting the following error: "could not open port 'COM3': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)"

### I used the following code:

```
import serial

def send_data_via_bluetooth(device_port, data):
    try:
        with serial.Serial(device_port, baudrate=9600) as ser:
            ser.write(data.encode())
        print("Data sent successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending data: {e}")

# Replace "COM3" with the appropriate COM port for your Bluetooth device
target_device_port = "COM3"
data_to_send = "Hello, Bluetooth!"

send_data_via_bluetooth(target_device_port, data_to_send)
```

---